# .cs class definitions auto-created in .ts

Tags: c#, typescript

I need to have a REST server (written in C#) pass a JSON object to/from my typescript client running in a browser. The best way to do this is define the class on the C# side that then creates a JSON object passed to the client where that JSON object matches the class structure in the client.

Which leads to the obvious question - is there a way to define the classes in C# and then run some program that will create the .ts class definitions? Or the reverse where I write out the classes in .TS and a program then creates matching .cs classes?

What I want to avoid is having to make sure any member added on one side is then added exactly the same on the other side.

And in a perfect world, the comments written for the class members are carried across too.

**Update:** I know I can write such a tool. However I'm hoping it already exists as that's a lot of work.

Comment: Sure, it would be possible to do so. You could build something simple that takes a compiled class, uses Reflection, and builds the corresponding typescript file, and even connect it to a build step if desired.

Comment: For the REST part: http://www.asp.net/web-api for the rest I would suggest using [t4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) you can configure them to run before compile and regenerate the files when you need

Answer (score 2):

Type lite http://type.litesolutions.net/ gets you halfway. Just the data member signature.

As you know json doesn't carry behaviour just data. So no functions will not be available on the other side. It's not a "transpiler"

> And in a perfect world, the comments written for the class members are carried across too.

Doesn't do this.

Comment: Yeah, the more I think about it the more I realize it would need to merge into my .ts classes so that the functions remain, but it marries up the POCO members that carry the data across. I'm guessing someday we'll get this, but I understand why it's not here yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I created a library which allows you to create JS-models for knockout and backbone out of c#-classes (mainly for domain-classes, so it comes with stuff like DataAnnotations-support, etc).

I added support for Typescript, as well as a small tool to create the files directly.

Check it out and if you have time, I'd love some feedback :)
https://jsmapper.codeplex.com/

Cheers,
Richard